# iis6 monitor that sends alarm when unusual requests happen

Tags: iis, web-server, monitoring, iis-6, asp.net

My iis6 server has been asked for more than 60 requests per second from on ip address. The requests made my server stop to work normally. I found the problem two days later.

Luckly, the user has stopped the behavior, and now my website works again. I worry that such thing might happen again.

Is there any monitor software that can detect such intensive requests from these odd users and alarm me with email?

Answer (score 1):

> ... and now my website works again

You can simply monitor the result of the attack (website working or not) with a good 3rd party website monitoring services like Gomez or AlertFox.

For a local installation, use e. g. Nagios.

There are tools that monitor traffic pattern, but this would be overkill for a small website.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already set up online monitor to test if the website work or not. You said there are tools that monitor traffic pattern. Can you tell me some of the best known tools?